# Visual Studio Code - Grey boxes

Tags: css, layout, visual-studio-code

I am using VSC and I do get some strange grey boxes in my editor, they are dynamic and annoying. If I change my Theme to a light one they disappear. Anyhow I would like to have it a dark thme and I could not find a solution for it.

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hgUz.png)
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dykCG.png)

Comment: have you tried to restart the VSC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are running into this bug: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12473

We're looking into the root cause of this issue. As a workaround, try changing your color profile as documented here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12473#issuecomment-269024219

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues, mine turned out to be an HDR issue.
I went into Display Settings and turned off Play HDR Games and Apps and the boxes went away.